# Access-Control-Allow-Origin Openlayers WFS

Tags: geoserver, wfs, openlayers-2, jetty

I try to use a WFS service with OpenStreetMap to request GeoServer GeoJSON file. First I had a error message on the Firefox `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/geoserver/robot/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=robot:geofield&outputFormat=aoolication%2Fjson. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).`

Then I pasted the following lines in the web.xml from /usr/share/geoserver/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

After when I go on http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ I have a HTTP ERROR: 503 and still have the same CORS header problem

I don't know what is wrong, maybe this method doesn't work with latest GeoServer versions

If someone has a good and clear answer, it will be great because I think I'm not the only one who want to use a wfs with GeoServer and OpenLayers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are using jetty and not catalina, I got same problem in Windows :

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/cross-origin-filter.html

Try putting instead in web.xml :

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And copy into C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.10.0\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\lib folder : jetty-servlets-9.2.13.v20150730.jar

Get jar needed from http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlets/, and check needed version from your folder C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.10.0\lib

Comment: in my package of Geoserver it was already there, so no needs to download from internetz. Worked for me, may work for others. $> cp $GEOSERVER_HOME\lib\jetty-servlets-9.2.13.v20150730.jar $GEOSERVER_HOME\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\lib

Comment: I didn't need to do your 2nd step in order to fix this issue.

Comment: To add details: with recent versions of Geoserver, the JAR file is already there. Not only do you not need to add it to WEB-INF/lib, but rather DON'T do it! Creating a copy can (as it did to me) confuse the server and make it unable to start! Simply uncomment the 2 filter text blocks, and everything it good.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just put this in my C:\Program Files\GeoServer\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\web.xml and works for me

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```