# GetFeatureInfo wms Leaflet

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wms, getfeatureinfo

I'm doing tests to query layers in Leaflet with WMS.

I'm seeing this

https://github.com/mmsmdali/ll1.0.3/blob/master/GetFeatureInfoWMS.htm and

http://jsfiddle.net/mmsmdali/ybzkg1tL/.

I'm trying to take WMS data from my Geoserver and replaced the WMS URL, the name of the layer, and the name of the fields in the popup window but I have a problem:
I see the layers in the map, but it does not make me select, and I do not see the fields in the popup.

Do I need to change some settings in my Geoserver?

Comment: Check the request sent when you click on layer using debug in Chrome, is there a request sent or no ?

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Try below answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210316/access-control-allow-origin-openlayers-wfs

Comment: Well, I did as you told me, but now when I select, I see the popup attributes but it does not highlight it. Why?